# Change CKEditor buttons color

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, vaadin, vaadin7

How can I change the background color of the buttons of the CKEditor? For example, this green button:

[image]

I am using CKEditor with Vaadin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the css for the skin you're using or simply override it in the page that hosts ckeditor. The OK button style is `cke_dialog_ui_button_ok` and the cancel button style is `cke_dialog_ui_button_cancel`.

So, to override the OK button background color and make it orange (just as an example), add this style definition in your page:

```
<style>
    a.cke_dialog_ui_button_ok {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffd800, #ff6a00) !important;
    }
</style>
```